# Remove roxygen tag/section

Tags: r, roxygen2

I’m defining a function that has attributes:

```
#' Some function
f = structure(function (n) n * 2, class = 'foo')
```

Unfortunately, Roxygen then produces a documentation that looks as follows:

> ```
> Description:
>
>      Some function
>
> Usage:
>
>      f
>
> Format:
>
>      function (n)  
>       - attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 7 19 7 36 19 36 7 7
>        .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x7fb88cc395c0> 
>       - attr(*, "class")= chr "foo"
> ```

I can fix the “Usage” block by manually specifying a different `@usage`. However, **I also want to get rid of the “Format” block**. The best I can achieve is to make it less conspicuous by specifying `@format .` (or similar) in the Roxygen comment. How can I remove it entirely?

Incidentally, it makes no difference if I define the function normally and add attributes later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@format NULL` to remove the format block.